# WPF Error handling multilanguage

Tags: wpf, mvvm

**Situation**:

I want to implement errorhandling in multiple languages in my WPF MVVM application. I did some research on the internet and came across this article:

- [Using a ViewModel to Provide Meaningful Validation Error Messages](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/)

**Question 1**:

*Can't you move the error handling to one place? In de Viewmodel or in the model, but I can't see the reason why both classes have a bit of the errorhandling...*

**Question 2**:

*In his example the error messages are set in the model class, is this good practice? It looks kind of "bad coding" to me... or am i wrong here?*

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: The thing to remember is the role of each part of the MVVM pattern. A certain amount of error handling needs to occur in the model, but it should only be related to business logic. Those errors need to be communicated to "client" of the model, or the view model. Similarly, some error handling can occur in the view model, but should be limited to the view model's role (ie. it needs to be independent of the view).

Question 2: I am not a fan of setting error messages in the model, nor in the view model. Error information needs to passed up to the view where it can be properly formatted and translated. This allows views to be created for different languages without having to change any code in the view model (or the model).

I hesitate to say "never", but I would think it is rare that a model need to know its language environment.

We are using the following for our multi-language support:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

This allows us to pass around error keys that can be translated in the view.

Hope this helps!